# Prevent converting two objects from two classes to bool when doing : if(a!=b)

Tags: c++, casting, boolean, implicit

I have two classes `A` and `B`, each having an `operator bool()` defined.

I recently came across a bug which was caused by:

```
A a;
B b;
if(a!=b)
{
    //...
}
```

The code compiled fine under gcc 4.9.1 and implicitly converted a and b to bool before comparison.

Is it possible to define something that would prevent this and cause a compile error, to force the programmer to use an explicit conversion function provided by A and B? Declarations of A and B should be unrelated, they are in to different headers.

Comment: You could overload `operator!=(A, B)`, or make your bool conversions `explicit`

Comment: Make the conversions to `bool` `explicit`? This is usually the right thing to do, and contexts like `if(a)` are still considered to be *"contextually converted to `bool`"*.

Comment: when you say "conversion", do you mean "comparison" ?

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that if(a) would still work with an explicit operator bool(), and this was the reason for most of my bool operator not to be explicit, with a lot of trouble sometimes. I will make them all explicit right now...

Comment: I just found out another bug by making it explicit : a QHash<A> was using the bool conversion for hashing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious way is to mark `operator bool()` explicit in either `A` or `B` (or both).   That will cause a compiler error.   Bear in mind it may cause some other usages of `A` or `B` - where such an implicit conversion works as intended - to also not compile.   There is no free lunch.

The intent of the code is presumably to compare the objects (or their data members in some way).   If that is so [that is a design choice for you] it would also be worth supplying a

```
  bool operator!=(const A&, const B&);      // usage a != b
  bool operator!=(const B&, const A&);    //   usage b != a
```

Depending on the types, passing one or more by value may be appropriate.   An alternative (e.g. if both types are `struct`/`class` types) is to implement `bool operator!=(const B &) const` as a member of `A`, and/or `bool operator!=(const A &) const` as a member of `B`.

Bear in mind that, if an `operator!=()` is supplied for two types, it may also be appropriate to provide other comparison operators (such as `==`).   That is a design decision though.

Comment: Could you explain about operator!() ? I did not know that this operator was involved here, or is this an error?

Comment: It's a good idea, not to make the comparison operator data members of the classes, since they usually should not require any private member access.

Comment: Sorry - wrote too fast.  `operator bool`.  I'll correct.

Answer (score 1):

Another "hack" would be to make the bool conversion explicit as M.M already mentioned, but this brings some other issues with it.

something like this:

```
class A {  // same for class B
public:
    explicit operator bool() {
        // some code
        return (true || false) && !(false && true);
    }
};
```

Now `if(a==b)` won't compile anymore, but `if(a)` and `if(b)` will. **HOWEVER**, this will lead to some other issues and unexpected behavior like `if(a==true)` also won't compile anymore, since `a` is casted to an integer; Which is also the reason why `if(a==b)` was compiling in the first place.

Another option would be to delete the implicit int conversion: `operator int() = delete;`

[Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3215d0be4abda3a7) is an example you can play arround and see what can happen if you mess with conversion operators...